# Win 2003 IIS6 - FTP Site Configuration

Tags: windows-server-2003, ftp, iis-6

I'm fairly new to server administration, so please be gentle with me.

On my dedicated server, in IIS6 manager, I've just added a new site called "upload-system", and modified the FTP settings so the home directory is \upload-system\www\uploads\, instead of just \upload-system. This is all okay but have one issue:

When I connect to the server using an FTP client, for example CuteFTP, I land in my new home directory, \uploads, just like I wanted, but from there, there's nothing stopping me from going back a directory, using the up-level/back button on the FTP client. I'm actually able to go right back to the c: directory on the server. I created this FTP site so my client can FTP his photos there, I really don't want any of their office staff having access to other parts of the server when connecting via FTP.

How do I stop this from happening in IIS6 manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to set up [Isolate Users Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/c0918f70-7a62-4d91-a05a-6db6ec4a3bb2.mspx?mfr=true)

That way, users are restricted access to their own home folders, and cannot navigate out of it

Comment: That's exactly what I need to set up, thanks Mathias, much appreciated.